# How can I print a list without the first square brackets?

Tags: python

How can I print a list without the first square brackets?

```
[[{'id': '5b0cecebc15ae360393438c2', 'owner': {'id': '58ebd0b12c593e5253505ad4'}, 'linked_id': None, 'type': 'product', 'name': 'Трансформаторное масло Т-1500у'}]]
```

At the same time, it is necessary to preserve its essence of the list.
So that the parser can read the id.

```
items = response['data']
usr_ids = items[i]["owner"]["id"]
```

Comment: You can reference objects contained within lists directly using the square bracket notation, like you have in your example. Try something like items[0], to access the first object in a list.

Comment: Just use string slicing: `str(my_list)[1:-1]`. If your list has more than one item in it, printing the first element (like `print(my_list[0])`) will lose the other elements in the list.

Comment: The fact is that I will have about 100 values in the list. And each one needs to be processed and extract "owner id"

Comment: What's your desired output? What parser are you talking about? You're not trying to make it into JSON, are you? Cause there's [a stdlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply print the first item of the list

```
lst = [[{'id': '5b0cecebc15ae360393438c2', 'owner': {'id': '58ebd0b12c593e5253505ad4'}, 'linked_id': None, 'type': 'product', 'name': 'Трансформаторное масло Т-1500у'}]]

print(lst[0])
```